# MySQL - Returning with the number of rows in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not too good with PHP, but I know some other similar languages.

Now what I am trying to do is get how many rows are in a table. Here is my code.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $num_rows;
```

Now this code returns with 1, when there is actually 3. Why is that?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check This

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM list"));
echo $result['count'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list");
$num_rows = mysql_fetch_object($result);
print_r($num_rows);
```

Note: Mysql_* functions are deprecated. Hence not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) as total_row FROM list");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>total_row</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['total_row'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM list");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $num_rows; // output 1;

$rows = mysql_fetch_object($result);
echo $rows->total; // output 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $num_rows;
```

If you want to get total number of row through `COUNT`, you can do like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("select count(*) FROM list");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

It return number of rows count in single column, then only it return  1

**Refer**:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

Answer (score 0):

Only change your query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $num_rows;
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns one row because, the query below returns only one value that is the number of rows.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list");
```

I think this should help:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list");
$num_rows = $result->fetchColumn();
echo $num_rows;
```